# Java 8 streaming refactoring - List<ObjA> to Map<String, List<ObjB>>

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the list into Map.

The list will be like

```
List<Employee> employeesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want this to be converted to Map like,

```
Map<String, List<RetiredEmployee>> empsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Here, the key will be employee name and the object will be RetiredEmployee which contains employee.

```
class RetiredEmployee {

   private final Employee employee;
   private final Optional<LocalDateTime> empJoinTime;

        RetiredEmployee(final Employee employee) {
            this.employee = employee;
            this.empJoinTime = getEmpJoinTime(employee);
        }
}
```

The below code works for,

```
List<Employee> to Map<String, List<Employee>>

employeesList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName));
```

But not sure, How to convert this Employee to new RetiredEmployee(employee) inside this groupingBy or streaming further.

Also, I need the last employees id from the list. Is it possible to have this also inside the streaming?

Also, would like to apply filter for employees whose join time is known or present.

Thanks

Comment: as a side note - avoid using Optionals as fields, they should _only_ be used as a return type where appropriate. nothing more.

Comment: @Aominè I believe that's a debated issue.

Comment: @shmosel true, but we should always strive to recommend people to use it the correct way.

Comment: @Aominè "correct" in whose view?

Comment: @shmosel as you've mentioned it's a _debated issue_ therefore let's leave it as that ;-) .

Comment: If Optional<LocalDateTime> empJoinTime is not a good practice, What is the best practice for setting unknown join time.  this.empJoinTime = getEmpJoinTime(employee).orElse(null); /// Something like this

Comment: As someone who has lived through this nightmare, don't use name as a key.  You will be disappointed by the number of "Smith, John" you end up with (the actual name varies by locale, but there's almost always a name that occurs more than once).  If you absolutely must use name as a key, build the knowledge that duplicates are going to occur into your architecture (i.e. expose some other actually unique key also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options. One is to use `Collectors.mapping()` to convert the values:

```
employeesList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                Collectors.mapping(RetiredEmployee::new, Collectors.toList())))
```

With Java 9, you can throw in a [`filtering()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector to exclude employees without a join time.

Or you can map the stream to `RetiredEmployee` and then extract the name indirectly. This makes it easier to add a filter on join time:

```
employeesList.stream()
        .map(RetiredEmployee::new)
        .filter(e -> e.getEmpJoinTime().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getEmployee().getName()))
```

As for getting the last employee from the list, I don't see the difficulty, or how it relates to streams altogether. Just use `employeesList.get(employeesList.size() - 1)`.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks.

Comment: employeesList.get(employeesList.size() - 1) may not work as I would like to get the last employee for whom joinTime is present. Is there any other way with the above streaming?

Comment: @user1578872 You can do the same stream as above and `reduce((a, b) -> b)` to get the last element. Or collect to a list and use `get()`.

Comment: Is it possible in the same stream iteration for getting the lastEmployee whose join time is present.

employeesList.stream()
        .map(RetiredEmployee::new)
        .filter(e -> e.getEmpJoinTime().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getEmployee().getName()))

Comment: I don't believe it is.

Comment: So, It needs iteration twice and the below code will run twice. employeesList.stream()
        .map(RetiredEmployee::new)